# How to indentation lines in VSCode like PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm, visual-studio-code

I'm using both PhpStorm and VSCode, they are both really good IDE. One of the most features I like in PhpStorm is `Format Code`, for example with this below code:

```
$full_name = 'Stackoverflow';
$age = 10;
```

When I select those lines and hit `Command + Alt + L`, it's automatically reformatted to

```
$full_name = 'Stackoverflow';
$age       = 10;
```

I have tried to use some extensions that support to format code in VSCode but none of them can do like PhpStorm.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension [Alignment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=annsk.alignment).

- select text
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>